# Grid not getting binded in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, webforms

I am using vb.net and trying to make edit/delete operation in it.

For that i have written the code to bind the grid, but when i am running the page,

Grid is not shown.

**aspx for grid:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpenceDate" HeaderText="Expence Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sum(Amount)" HeaderText="Amount" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code for binding the grid:

```
 Try
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("select expDate,sum(Amount) from expence_VB where expDate between '" + DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text) + "' and '" + DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text) + "' group by ExpDate", con)
            ds = New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds)
            gv.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            gv.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

**Note:**

I have done edit columns and turned off autogenerate fields.

For bound fields i have made DataField same as column name in query which i have written to bind the grid.

Is that any mistake in this?

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake at your query select, that query sum(Amount) not give column name.
Try this:
Change your select query from

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter("select expDate,sum(Amount) from expence_VB where expDate between '" + DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text) + "' and '" + DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text) + "' group by ExpDate", con)
```

Become

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter("select expDate,sum(Amount) as SumAmount from expence_VB where expDate between '" + DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text) + "' and '" + DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text) + "' group by ExpDate", con)
```

And then in aspx grid, you can change this code:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="sum(Amount)" HeaderText="Amount" />
```

Become :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="SumAmount" HeaderText="Amount" />
```